# curl identity on $\mathcal{D}'\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ for $v\in H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I need to show that if $u\in H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)^2$ such that $\text{div }u=0$, then if
$$w=\text{curl }u=\partial_1 u_2-\partial_2 u_1$$
in $\mathcal{D}'\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ (space of distributions),
we have
$$\text{curl }\left(\left(u\cdot\nabla\right)u\right)=u\cdot \nabla w$$
where $$\left(u\cdot\nabla\right)u=\left(\sum_j u_j\partial_j u_i\right)_i$$
I have shown this holds if $u\in\mathcal{C}^2\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)^2$, how can I pass it to the Sobolev space ? I thought about using density of smooth functions with compact support, but I do not know how this works in details.

I cannot pass all the derivatives to the test functions because I have a dot product.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: What does $u\cdot w$ mean? Just multiplication?

Comment: @JackyChong It is a scalar product.

Comment: It might be a dumb question, but isn't curl is a scalar in the plane?

Comment: @JackyChong Sorry ! There is obviously a $\nabla$ operator missing in front of $w$... Fixed on the original post.

Comment: i can't make sense of $u\cdot \nabla w$, since $\nabla w\in H^{-1}$...?

Comment: Because the divergence of $u$ is 0, in the sense of distributions, we have 
$$\int \left(u\cdot\nabla w\right)\varphi=\int div(uw)\varphi=-\int wu\cdot\nabla\varphi$$

This term is well defined if $u\in H^1$ as $w$ will be in $L^2$ (and use Hölder inequality-here Cauchy-Schwarz actually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the proof.

If $v\in H^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)^{2}$, let $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$.

On one side, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left(v\cdot \omega\right)\varphi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\text{div}\left(v w\right)\varphi=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}wv\cdot\nabla\varphi =-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\text{curl}\left(v\right)v\cdot\nabla\varphi
 \end{equation*}
as $\text{div}(v)=0$.
and on the other side
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\text{curl}\left(\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)v\right)\varphi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)v\wedge\nabla\varphi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)v\cdot\left(\nabla\varphi\right)^{\perp}
 \end{equation*}
where we noted
\begin{equation*}
  \left(\nabla\varphi\right)^{\perp}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \partial_{2}\varphi\\
   -\partial_{1}\varphi
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
As such

\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)v\cdot\left(\nabla\varphi\right)^{\perp}+\text{curl}\left(v\right)v\cdot\nabla\varphi
  &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left[-v_{1}\partial_{1}v_{2}-v_{2}\partial_{2}v_{2}+v_{1}\partial_{1}v_{2}-v_{1}\partial_{2}v_{1}\right]\partial_{1}\varphi\\
  &~~~~~~~~+\left[v_{1}\partial_{1}v_{1}+v_{2}\partial_{2}v_{1}+v_{2}\partial_{1}v_{2}-v_{2}\partial_{2}v_{1}\right]\partial_{2}\varphi\\
  &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}-\left[v_{2}\partial_{2}v_{2}+v_{1}\partial_{2}v_{1}\right]\partial_{1}\varphi\\
  &~~~~~~~~+\left[v_{1}\partial_{1}v_{1}+v_{2}\partial_{1}v_{2}\right]\partial_{2}\varphi\\
  &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\left[\frac{v_{2}^{2}}{2}+\frac{v_{1}^{2}}{2}\right]\partial_{2}\partial_{1}\varphi-\left[\frac{v_{1}^{2}}{2}+\frac{v_{2}^{2}}{2}\right]\partial_{1}\partial_{2}\varphi\\
  &=0
 \end{align*}
Everything is well defined as $v_{i}\in H^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$ for $i=1,2$ (use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\partial_{i}\varphi$ is bounded for the first two lines, or the fact that $\partial_{1}\partial_{2}\varphi$ is bounded for the third).